# BigQuery Struct Aggregation

Tags: struct, google-bigquery, aggregation

I am processing an ETL job on BigQuery, where I am trying to reconcile data where there may be conflicting sources. I frist used `array_agg(distinct my_column ignore nulls)` to find out where reconciliation was needed and next I need to prioritize data per column base on the source source.

I thought to `array_agg(struct(data_source, my_column))` and hoped I could easily extract the preferred source data for a given column. However, with this method, I failed aggregating data as a struct and instead aggregated data as an array of struct.

Considered the simplified example below, where I will prefer to get `job_title` from HR and `dietary_pref` from Canteen:

```
with data_set as (
    select 'John' as employee, 'Senior Manager' as job_title, 'vegan' as dietary_pref, 'HR' as source
    union all
    select 'John' as employee, 'Manager' as job_title, 'vegetarian' as dietary_pref, 'Canteen' as source
    union all
    select 'Mary' as employee, 'Marketing Director' as job_title, 'pescatarian' as dietary_pref, 'HR' as source
    union all
    select 'Mary' as employee, 'Marketing Manager' as job_title, 'gluten-free' as dietary_pref, 'Canteen' as source

)

select employee,
       array_agg(struct(source, job_title)) as job_title,
       array_agg(struct(source, dietary_pref)) as dietary_pref,
from data_set
group by employee
```

The data I get for John with regard to the job title is:
`[{'source':'HR', 'job_title':'Senior Manager'}, {'source': 'Canteen', 'job_title':'Manager'}]`
Whereas I am trying to achieve:
`[{'HR' : 'Senior Manager', 'Canteen' : 'Manager'}]`

With a struct output, I was hoping to then easily access the preferred source using `my_struct.my_preferred_source`. I this particular case I hope to invoke `job_title.HR` and `dietary_pref.Canteen`.

Hence in pseudo-SQL here I imagine I would :

```
select employee,
        AGGREGATE_JOB_TITLE_AS_STRUCT(source, job_title).HR  as job_title,
        AGGREGATE_DIETARY_PREF_AS_STRUCT(source, dietary_pref).Canteen as dietary_pref, 
from data_set group by employee
```

The output would then be:

[image: expected_output]

I'd like help here solving this. Perhaps that's the wrong approach altogether, but given the more complex data set I am dealing with I thought this would be the preferred approach (albeit failed).

Open to alternatives. Please advise. Thanks

*Notes: I edited this post after Mikhail's answer, which solved my problem using a slightly different method than I expected, and added more details on my intent to use a single struct per employee*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below

```
select employee,
  array_agg(struct(source as job_source, job_title) order by if(source = 'HR', 1, 2) limit 1)[offset(0)].*,
  array_agg(struct(source as dietary_source, dietary_pref) order by if(source = 'HR', 2, 1) limit 1)[offset(0)].*
from data_set
group by employee
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Update:

use below for clarified output

```
select employee,
  array_agg(job_title order by if(source = 'HR', 1, 2) limit 1)[offset(0)] as job_title,
  array_agg(dietary_pref order by if(source = 'HR', 2, 1) limit 1)[offset(0)] as dietary_pref
from data_set
group by employee
```

with output

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mikhail! Always here to save the day! So in your solution it's great: you stick with the array of structs. I'm also learning (1) you can pass an order by in array_agg() and (2) that you can pass a conditional in order by. Top. 
For the sake of learning though: is there a way I can aggregate a single struct instead of an array of structs? In the end I'd want to be able to output job_title.HR to get the HR job title from HR source. Is that doable? If so how?

Comment: your requirements are not clear. i recommend you to provide good example of expected output (based on already provided sample of input data)

Comment: Hi Mikhail: in the initial post, I wrote "The data I get for John with regard to the job title is: [{'HR' : 'Senior Manager'}, {'Canteen' : 'Manager'}] Whereas I am trying to achieve: [{'HR' : 'Senior Manager', 'Canteen' : 'Manager'}]". Actually I was wrong about the part I achieved, which in fact is [{"source": "HR", "job_title" : "Senior Manager"}, {"source": "Canteen" : "Manager"}]. However, I was trying to get the source name as the key and the job title as the value. So the objective was described correctly, namely I wanted to output: [{'HR' : 'Senior Manager', 'Canteen' : 'Manager'}]

Comment: still not clear what exactly output is expected - at least to me not clear at all! can you maybe provide schema of expected output?

Comment: I added a pseudo-code of how I'd expect building some struct and call the struct keys, and expected output. I hope this clarifies that, sorry if my request is unclear. Perhaps, I'm asking something SQL doesn't do.